# Ansible on Ubuntu 16.04 error on ping command

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I have a vagrant Ubuntu 16.04 VM with Ansible installed (using `sudo apt install ansible`) i config the `/etc/ansible/hosts` file and when i try to run `ansible all -m ping` i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 85, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli.run())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/cli/adhoc.py", line 190, in run
    self._tqm.cleanup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 245, in cleanup
    self._cleanup_processes()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 249, in _cleanup_processes
    self._result_prc.terminate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/process/result.py", line 89, in terminate
    super(ResultProcess, self).terminate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 137, in terminate
    self._popen.terminate()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'
```

I tried the same installations and config file on a Vagrant Centos7 image and everything works fine.

I was not able to find something similar but maybe my search skills are not so good. Does anyone encounter this? Is there something else to install on Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't install Ansible with APT unless you are running a museum of technology.

Comment: You're saying I should use 'pip install ansible'?

Comment: Yes, I am saying.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for the Ubuntu version. Don't install it by using `sudo apt install ansible` only, you need to install it from the ansible repo.

Run this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ansible -y
```

I don't know why it works like this, I don't have time to research it but it works using the `ppa:ansible/ansible`. I guess the one from the apt is obsolete.

PS: thanks for the downvote whoever downvoted.